# JPEGencode issue in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is my code. What I m trying to achieve is to be able to capture an image from the the camera and upload it onto a media server but so far I have not been able to encode it succesfully .Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Here is the code

```
  var imagePromise:MediaPromise = event.data;
  imageLoader = new Loader();
  imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, asyncImageLoaded );
  imageLoader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cameraError );
  imageLoader.loadFilePromise( imagePromise );
  function asyncImageLoaded(event:Event):void
    {

var destination:String = "upload.php";
var now:Date = new Date();
var fileName = "IMG" + now.fullYear + now.month + ".jpg";
var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(imageLoader.content);
var bitmapData:BitmapData = image.bitmapData;
var j = new JPGEncoder(80);
var bytes:ByteArray = j.encode(bitmapData);

      }
```

This is the error I get when i try to encode the image

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Answer (score 1):

which line?  1009 means you're trying to access a variable of something that is NULL.  I'm guessing in this case, it's probably the line:

```
var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(imageLoader.content);
```

Try adding this:

```
if (imageLoader.content is Bitmap) {
    var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(imageLoader.content);
} else {
    throw new Error("What the heck bob?");
}
```

If it's an error, I bet the content was not decoded properly (which could mean a mime-type that wasn't image/jpg)

Additionally, you could probably use the native jpeg encoder for speed: (flash 11 i believe?)

```
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
bitmapData.encode(new Rectangle(0,0,640,480), new flash.display.JPEGEncoderOptions(), byteArray);
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS4768145595f94108-17913eb4136eaab51c7-8000.html

Comment: so it does throws an error..  how can I make sure that I get the right mime-type

Comment: How can I Access the data stored in var imagePromise globaly in the program.? any clues

Comment: trace(imageLoader.content)   What does it give you?

Comment: <?php header('Content-Type: image/jpg'); ?>

Comment: I get null after I did a trace

Comment: yeah, then it didn't know how to decode whatever you were sending over.  You'll have to check your PHP script